# Does the definition of linear code implies that $E(c_1 + c_2) = E(c_1) + E(c_2)$ for encoding function $E$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, coding-theory

I know that if $c_1$ and $c_2$ are two codewords in a linear binary code $C$, then $c_1 + c_2$ is also in $C$.

However, does the definition of linear (binary) code (as a subspace of $\mathbb{F}_2^{n}$) implies that $E(c_1 + c_2) = E(c_1) + E(c_2)$, where $E$ is some encoding function?

Since Hamming code uses a generator matrix $G$ to generate code, it satisfies $G(c_1 + c_2) = G(c_1) + G(c_2)$. Is this valid for all linear codes? Or, are there linear codes that do not satisfy $E(c_1 + c_2) = E(c_1) + E(c_2)$ for encoding functions $E$?

Comment: Yes, but summation is defined in a field. If it is GF(2), for example, you need boolean arithmetic.

Comment: @msm Boolean arithmetic is assumed. How to prove $E(c_1 + c_2) = E(c_1) + E(c_2)$?

Comment: But that is the definition of linear..

Comment: @msm I thought that defining a linear code $C$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{F}_2^{n}$ only means that $C$ (as a *set*) is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. However, $E(c_1 + c_2) = E(c_1) + E(c_2)$ requires the encoding *function* to be linear too.

Comment: If it is a filed then it is closed under addition and multiplication. A linear code means the property you want holds.

Comment: @msm Sorry to bother you with such a simple question. However, I am still confused. Do you have references that state this property explicitly for linear code? Please see my updated post.

Comment: @hengxin [this, Definition 8](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~venkatg/teaching/codingtheory/notes/notes1.pdf) ?

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks. I am satisfied with this definition. Would you like to convert it into an answer?

Comment: @hengxin Sorry, I was sleeping :)

Comment: @ClementC. I have converted your helpful comment into an answer. Great thanks.

Comment: @hengxin You're welcome!

Comment: @msm "A linear code means the property you want holds." I don't think so, see a counterexample in my answer.

Comment: @leonbloy The point is  that "linear" refers to the encoding function (at least in the most common definition). However, you reduced it to a code defined on a linear subspace.

Comment: @msm: We might be reading different textbooks, but I'd definitely say the "most common definition" of a linear code refers to the codewords alone, and never to the encoding function. The link in hengxin's answer is just one example. (Lin-Costello, Morelos-Zaragoza, Richardson-Urbanke, Huffman-Pless,  Moreira-Farrel... and WIkipedia are others)

Comment: @leonbloy l can see some common textbooks in your list. So it seems the interpretation is different. Your interpretation overlaps with a code that is defined in a linear field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not implied by the definition of a linear code. The definition of a linear code is not related to the encoding function, only with the (unmapped) set of codewords.

> A block code of lenght $n$ and $2^k$ codewords is called a **linear**
>   $(n,k)$ code if and only if its $2^k$ codewords form a $k$-dimensional subspace of the vector space of all the $n$-tuples over
>   the field $GF(2)$

(Definition of binary linear codes from [Lin & Costello](https://books.google.com.ar/books/about/Error_Control_Coding.html?id=BG08Zylo_7gC)):

So, strictly speaking, it can well happen for a linear code that $E(c_1 +c_2) \ne E(c_1) + E(c_2)$. 
For example:

$$c_1: 00 \to 100$$
$$c_2: 01 \to 110$$
$$c_3: 10 \to 010$$
$$c_4: 11 \to 000$$

This is a linear code (the codewords form a linear subspace), but the encoding function is not: $E(c_1+c_2)=E(c_2) \ne E(c_1) + E(c_2)$

*However*, it's easy to show that given a set of codewords that form a subspace (which is to say, given a linear code), an encoding function can be used that is also linear (and which can be expressed as a generator matrix, which is multiplied by the input).  And, in practice, that's always preferred.

(Incidentally, that's also why every "real" linear code maps the zero input to the zero codeword - a property that is not strictly required for having a linear code, but for having a linear encoding function).

Comment: Thanks. This answer completely solves my confusion.

Answer (score 4):

I am satisfied with definition 8 given in the [lecture note by Venkatesan Guruswami](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~venkatg/teaching/codingtheory/notes/notes1.pdf) mentioned by @Clement C. in a comment. It claims that a linear code has a linear transformation for encoding.

> **Definition 8 (Generator matrix and encoding)** Let $C \subseteq \mathbb{F}_q^n$ be a linear code of dimension $k$. A matrix $G \in \mathbb{F}_q^{n×k}$ is said to be a generator matrix for $C$ if its $k$ columns span $C$.The generator matrix $G$ provides a way to encode a message $x \in \mathbb{F}_q^k$ (thought of as a column vector) as the codeword $Gx \in C \subseteq \mathbb{F}_q^n$. Thus a linear code has an encoding map $E : \mathbb{F}_q^k \to \mathbb{F}_q^n$ which is a linear transformation $x \to Gx$.

Comment: That is good. You can also refer to error control coding textbooks.